# How to print json data using laravel

Tags: laravel

I am new in laravel

```
[{
    "id":1,
    "name":"demo",
    "slug":"demo",
    "status":1,
    "get_total_record":{
        "store_id":1,
        "counts":2
    }
}]
```

This is my record from database.

how can I print counts value.

I am using `$get_total_record->counts`, but it give error.

Comment: what you did, that you are getting Json string ?  can you share your Methods/code ?

Comment: More than one record geting in json string, json string is ok but onlyy displaying problem. i don't know to how to print. i also use foreach() loop in view.

Comment: are you writing API ? please share your method through which you are fetching records from DB, eg: `User::where('active',1)->get();`

Comment: Provide me, full query/method, you shared results, I am asking for query

Comment: @Qazi   public function getTotalRecord()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Post')
            ->selectRaw('store_id, count(*) as counts')
            ->where('status',1)
            ->groupBy('store_id');
    }

Comment: also share your Error, and query which you are using for this relationship to get total counts

Comment: @Qazi Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136510/discussion-between-qazi-and-ankit-virani).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this. actually you are using Relationship and getting count from relationship variable, directly which in not possible an incorrect way, Follow this. share your result please

```
$store=new Store;
$storeList=Store::with('getTotalRecord')->get();
```

**//Edited, Now you have to loop through the store list, this for your understanding**

```
foreach($storelist as $store){
  echo "Count is: ".$store->getTotalRecord->count()."<br />";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are returning a variable from your controller. Let's call it `$post`. You can display like this.

```
{{ $post->get_total_record->counts }}
```

Comment: It's give error Trying to get property of non-object

Answer (score 0):

If it is already a json then say you saved it in variable $tests, try:

```
foreach($storeLists as $sl){
    if(isset($sl->get_total_record)){
        if(isset($sl->get_total_record->counts)){
            echo $sl->get_total_record->counts;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an instance of a model:

```
{{ json_decode($demo->get_total_record, true)['count'] }}
```

If you have a collection, you need to iterate over it:

```
@foreach ($demos as $demo)
    {{ json_decode($demo->get_total_record, true)['count'] }}
@endforeach
```

Alternatively, you could use [casting](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting) for the `get_total_record` field:

```
protected $casts = [
    'get_total_record' => 'array',
];
```

And access data with:

```
{{ $demo->get_total_record['count'] }}
```

Comment: I am also use this but not print count value

Comment: @AnkitVirani what exactly solution do you use? If the first one, please post the result of `{{ dd($demo->get_total_record) }}`

Comment: I used both solution.